# Why does chaining methods in a statement fail to give an expected result?

Tags: c++, filesystems, method-chaining, static-code-analysis, buildconfiguration

I can compute a `const char*` presentation of an `std::filesystem::path` variable like that:

```
std::filesystem::path path1(L"ConsoleApplication1.cpp");
std::string strPath1 = path1.string();
const char* charArrPath1 = strPath1.c_str();
```

But if I omit explicit assignment of a `string` variable and use method chaining in a char array initialization statement

```
const char* charArrPath1 = path1.string().c_str();
```

variable `charArrPath1` contains garbage after execution.

How come the chaining of methods seemingly fails to work?

PS If I explicitly assign the result of `string()` on `path1` to some unrelated variable after initialization of `charArrPath1`, I do have the result as expected:

```
std::filesystem::path path1(L"ConsoleApplication1.cpp");
const char* charArrPath1 = path1.string().c_str();
std::string strPathUnrelated = path1.string();
std::cout << charArrPath1 << std::endl;
```

EPILEGOMENON:

The method chaining seems to fail when the code is run in x86 configurations, both Debug and Release. When run in an x64 Release configuration, the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path path1(L"ConsoleApplication1.cpp");
    const char* charArrPath1 = path1.string().c_str();

    std::cout << charArrPath1 << std::endl;
}
```

prints out

```
ConsoleApplication1.cpp
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Because [`std::filesystem::path::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) returns by-value, what it returns is a [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime), which will be destroyed after the full expression, left the pointer got from `c_str()` dangled.

As you've tried, the pointer won't be dangled if you use a named variable, which won't be destroyed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

"Dangling pointers is the darkest nightmare of a language that relies on pointers and explicit release of resources" (from `A brief introduction to C++'s model for type- and resource-safety' by Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter, section 3. Memory safety, p. 4)

Chasing a seemingly intermittent bug of my rather biggish program, I eventually found it brute-force, iterating over breakpoints. It happened to hide in rather obscure lines that construct filesystem path hints in a rarely executed branch. I wondered why 'Code Analysis', an awesome instrument to enforce type- and resource-safety of your code that you launch checking 'Enable Code Analysis on Build' in Visual Studio's project properties, failed to warn me of these lines, and posted a cautious question to Stack Overflow in a hope that someone teach me to use Code Analysis.

Curious, I also started to browse MSDN documentation and learnt that a Microsoft Native Recommended Rules ruleset, a default for C++ projects, does not contain the entire C++ Core Guideline set. I selected a Microsoft All Rules ruleset, run it against the old version of my program, and it flagged culprit lines with warnings C26486 Don't pass a pointer that may be invalid to a function.

As for PS and 'Epilegomenon' sections of my question, I found out that the reported behavior for different configurations is valid only for the v142 platform toolset, and (probably) is of a minor significance.